# Can't append html in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, internet-explorer-11

I made a code to pass through a table and made a total of each number in a specific column. Everything's working fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari even IE 9 and IE 10. But this is not working in IE 11. The code don't append the sentences.

Here's the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    total = 0;
    total_continue = 0;
    jQuery('#qqp_profile_meta_box_r_profile_formation table tbody tr').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('the_header_row') || jQuery(this).hasClass('the_template_row') || jQuery(this).hasClass('the_final_row') ){
            // Nothing for the moment
        }else{
            total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($('td input',this).val());
        }

    });

    jQuery('#qqp_profile_meta_box_r_profile_formation').append("<p class='total-heure-formation' style='margin-left:63%;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold'>Total : " + total +  " heures de formation</p>");
    jQuery('#qqp_profile_meta_box_r_profile_formation').append("<p class='total-heure-formation-continue' style='margin-left:63%;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold'>Total : " + total_continue +  " heures de formation continue (" + total_continue * 2.0 + " unités)</p>");
    jQuery('#qqp_profile_meta_box_r_profile_formation').append("<input name='total-heure-formation-continue' class='input-formation-continue' type='hidden' value='" + total_continue + "' /> ");
});
```

UPDATE :

I can't really explain it. But when i removed the .ready function, it worked.

Comment: Are errors reported in the browser console?

Comment: When you say 'you can't append in IE11' what exactly happens? Nothing at all?  Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Also `total` and `total_continue` should probably be declared with `var`.

Comment: No errors related to the code in the browser console.